# Ingress annotations provisions unnecessary AWS classic load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

Within my AWS EKS cluster provisioning an AWS application load balancer using annotations on the Ingress object. Additionally an unnecessary classic load balancer is being provisioned. Any ideas or best practice on how to prevent this?

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "api" {
  metadata {
     name = "${var.project_prefix}-api-service"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "${var.project_prefix}-api"
    }
    port {
      name = "http"
      port        = 80
      target_port = 1337
    }
    port {
      name = "https"
      port = 443
      target_port = 1337
    }
    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "api" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name = "${var.project_prefix}-api"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme" = "internet-facing"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type" = "instance"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn" = local.api-certificate_arn
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name" = "${var.project_prefix}-api"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports" = "[{\"HTTP\": 80}, {\"HTTPS\":443}]"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect" = "{\"Type\": \"redirect\", \"RedirectConfig\": { \"Protocol\": \"HTTPS\", \"Port\": \"443\", \"StatusCode\": \"HTTP_301\"}}"
    }
  }
  spec {
    backend {
      service_name = kubernetes_service.api.metadata.0.name
      service_port = 80
    }
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          path = "/*"
           backend {
            service_name = "ssl-redirect"
            service_port = "use-annotation"
          }
        }
      }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are creating the Classic LoadBalancer under `resource "kubernetes_service" "api"` I didn't understand the point here, If you don't want to create additional Load Balancer, Change service Type from `LoadBalancer` to `NodePort` or `ClusterIP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LoadBalancer service is responsible for deploying the classic load balancer, and if you just need an application load balancer, is unnecessary.

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "api" {
  metadata {
     name = "${var.project_prefix}-api-service"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "${var.project_prefix}-api"
    }
    port {
      name = "http"
      port        = 80
      target_port = 1337
    }
    port {
      name = "https"
      port = 443
      target_port = 1337
    }
    type = "ClusterIP" # See comments below
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "api" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name = "${var.project_prefix}-api"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "alb"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type" = "ip" # See comments below
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme" = "internet-facing"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type" = "instance"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn" = local.api-certificate_arn
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name" = "${var.project_prefix}-api"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports" = "[{\"HTTP\": 80}, {\"HTTPS\":443}]"
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect" = "{\"Type\": \"redirect\", \"RedirectConfig\": { \"Protocol\": \"HTTPS\", \"Port\": \"443\", \"StatusCode\": \"HTTP_301\"}}"
    }
  }
  spec {
    backend {
      service_name = kubernetes_service.api.metadata.0.name
      service_port = 80
    }
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          path = "/*"
           backend {
            service_name = "ssl-redirect"
            service_port = "use-annotation"
          }
        }
      }
     }
  }
}
```

### Traffic Modes

Depending on your cluster and networking setup, you might be able to use `ip` target type, where the load balancer can communicate directly with Kubernetes pods via their IP (so `ClusterIP` service types are fine) if you have a CNI configuration, or use `instance` in conjunction with `NodePort` service types as the load balancer cannot directly access the pod IPs. Some relevant links below:

[ALB Target Types](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/ingress/annotations/#target-type)

[VPC CNI EKS Plugin](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s)

### Load Balancer Types

Some relevant links regarding Kubernetes load balancing and EKS load balancers. Note that Ingress resources are layer 7 and load balance service resources are layer 4, hence ALBs deployed for EKS ingress resources and NLBs for load balanced service resources:

[Rancher Kubernetes Load Balancers](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/k8s-in-rancher/load-balancers-and-ingress/load-balancers/)

[AWS Load Balancer Comparison](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Not sure if I get the AWS Controller's design since I do find it kinda confusing to use Ingress resources to provision Application Load Balancers but Service resources to provisions Classic/Network Load Balancers? Is there any logic or concept behind this that I am not aware of?

Comment: Kubernetes ingress resources are Layer 7, while load balance services are layer 4, hence the different types used across the resources. I'll update the post with some relevant links.

Comment: The Service object actually has to be of type "NodePort", as stated in the official docs:

"Ingress traffic starts at the ALB and reaches the Kubernetes nodes through each service's NodePort. This means that services referenced from ingress resources must be exposed by type:NodePort in order to be reached by the ALB." — https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/how-it-works/

Comment: Really depends on the VPC networking and cluster setup. If it's set up with ENI, you can set annotation ```alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type``` to ```ip``` and the load balancer directs directly to pod IPs, but yes otherwise you are correct, instead of ClusterIP, use NodePort as the load balancers may not be able to access the pod IPs directly.

Comment: Have updated the answer to add more information.